# Incorrect random number output issue in Java (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, random

I have a random number variable named 'loadG1' that is outputted after the user presses enter on an EditText. There are a few if statements at the bottom of the coe displayed below, with the purpose of determining the length of loadG1 (in terms of digits) depending on the user's score. The user gets a point added each time their input matches loadG1. My problem is that sometimes on the outputted randoms before 3 points (>=0), I get a six digit number. This is only meant to happen when they have 3 or more points. This also happens at other stages, e.g: 7 digits meant to be outputted by 8 are instead. The pattern seems to almost work perfectly, but at times one digit more than the limit is outputted for that user's score. Never one digit less, but either the right amount or sometimes one more.

Here's the code:

```
final Random generateG1 = new Random();
            final int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(99999)+10000;
            final TextView number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
            number.setText(""+loadG1);

            final CountDownTimer loop = new CountDownTimer(3500, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    number.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    final TextView prompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prompt);
                    prompt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    prompt.setText(" Enter the number");
                    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAnswer);
                    input.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    input.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                switch (keyCode) {
                                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                                        Editable answer = input.getText();
                                        int finalAnswer = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(answer));
                                        int finalLoadG1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(number.getText()));
                                        input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        if (finalAnswer == finalLoadG1) {
                                            score++;
                                        }

                                        number.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                        if (score>=0) {
                                            int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(99999)+10000;
                                            number.setText(""+loadG1);
                                        }
                                        if (score>=3){
                                            int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(999999)+100000;
                                            number.setText(""+loadG1);
                                        }
                                        if (score>=6){
                                            int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(9999999)+1000000;
                                            number.setText(""+loadG1);
                                        }
                                        if (score>=10){
                                            int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(99999999)+10000000;
                                            number.setText(""+loadG1);
                                        }

                                        input.getText().clear();

                                        start();
```

I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me what's causing this error, and how to resolve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: already asked by same user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117497/random-number-generator-issue-android-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the conditions.

1. Either reverse the order of if statements , or
2. Add < condition also to if statements.

And make use of else also.

```
    if (score>=10){
        int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(99999999)+10000000;
        number.setText(""+loadG1);
    }
    else if (score>=6){
        int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(9999999)+1000000;
        number.setText(""+loadG1);
    }
    else if (score>=3){
        int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(999999)+100000;
        number.setText(""+loadG1);
    }else if (score>=0) {
        int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(99999)+10000;
        number.setText(""+loadG1);
    }
```

or

```
    if (score>=0 && score<3) {
        int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(99999)+10000;
        number.setText(""+loadG1);
    }
    else if (score>=3 && score<6){
        int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(999999)+100000;
        number.setText(""+loadG1);
    }
    else if (score>=6 && score<10){
        int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(9999999)+1000000;
        number.setText(""+loadG1);
    }
    else if (score>=10){
        int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(99999999)+10000000;
        number.setText(""+loadG1);
    }
```

Comment: I was confident this would work, so I tried the following (shown in post edit) but was disappointed to receive the same results.

Comment: @User44 it should work as intended. what is the problem now?

Comment: Same issue as before. I had also expected it to work perfectly, but I'm still getting some 6-digit numbers before the user gets 3 points as their score. I'm not so sure as to why this is happening.

Comment: that's because you are adding 10000 after generating random no. So if generated no is greater than 89999 then it will be a 6 digit number

Comment: You mean <code>generateG1.nextInt(99999)+10000;</code>? I thought that sets the minimum value to 10000, like every other number after a +.

Comment: yes, min will be 10000 but max is not limited to 99999, then you need to do generateG1.nextInt(89999)+10000;